# Href and onclick events not working on <area>

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, hover

I've made an area map with mapper.js and everything seems fine until I put an event (href or onclick) on the same area. I´m using primefaces xhtml.

The problem I have is this:

1. When I call the mapper.js then the link stop working, but "hover" works fine.
2. If I didn´t call the "mapper.js" then link works fine but obviously hover didn´t works.

Please, tell me, how can I make both "hover" and "onclick/href" works fine...

Here there is the **index.xhtml** file:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1"  style="display:block;" id="panel_home">
    <h:form id="department_form" style="display:none">
        <ui:repeat value="#{departamentsController.departments}" var="department" >
            <p:commandButton id="departmentButton" value="#{department.name}" oncomplete="PF('dialog').show();" styleClass="#{'department_'.concat(department.id)}" update="listFilesForm" actionListener="#{fileSearchController.filesByDepartment(department)}"/>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>

    <h:graphicImage id="graphicImage1" ismap="true" styleClass="mapper iborder456c74 icolord76f47" url="/resources/images/mapa1.png" usemap="#map1" />
        <map name="map1" id="map1">
            <area href="JavaScript: document.getElementById('department_form:j_idt13:13:departmentButton').click();"  shape="poly" coords="434,166,438,162,439,158,445,148,450,137,456,134,458,126,461,121,466,120,470,119,476,121,493,89,505,85,515,82,526,80,536,73,547,63,539,47,529,44,524,42,522,40,517,40,514,41,514,45,510,45,509,43,507,46,503,48,502,46,498,49,501,52,499,55,494,58,492,57,492,53,485,52,484,54,483,59,483,64,477,76,467,81,453,85,444,88,436,95,423,103,418,106,410,113,394,115,390,122,389,128,388,136,392,140,398,139,406,139,412,141,410,148,413,150,418,146,421,149,423,153,423,159,420,165,419,169,427,165" />
            <area href="JavaScript: document.getElementById('department_form:j_idt13:14:departmentButton').click();" shape="poly" coords="371,260,377,254,369,244,368,239,363,232,357,227,365,222,373,220,375,221,377,218,366,198,360,188,369,172,376,170,384,167,390,163,395,163,393,158,391,152,392,148,390,143,388,139,394,113,386,114,378,113,372,111,368,107,361,107,358,110,353,115,352,120,352,123,349,132,344,142,342,146,335,145,334,142,327,142,327,139,333,137,333,131,328,126,318,124,316,126,318,131,319,141,320,150,320,158,315,163,310,170,308,176,305,182,305,186,312,188,314,195,311,198,309,202,312,210,313,216,315,220,313,226,320,232,329,243,336,240,339,243,344,243,351,252" />

        </map>
    </p:panelGrid>
</ui:define>
```

So, no matter if I use "href="JavaScript: ..." or "onclick=", nothing changes. I´ve searched for a lot of places an made a lot of tests, but still dont´t know how to make "hover" on areas and "onclick/href" both works fine.

I have like 30 areas, but for you to know I've copied just two.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? Please create an [mcve]. You'll see that there will most likely be no PF tag left. This all is plain HTML/javascript (not xhtml) problem

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Kukeltje I will remind what u said about best ways to make a question... Regarding my own question, just in case anyone have a similar problem. A friend told me that for best practices in the <area> is better to have an onclick event rather than an href. And when you have a lot of <areas> (for instance a map), is better to call the action by Class rather than by Id. Also he show me the following event that will trigger the action and also wll show the hover effect: `onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('nameofclasshere')[0].click();"` ... thank you for the help :)

Comment: Please improve the Question to (a.o. remove all PF stuff since it is totally unrelated)

Answer (score 0):

In an area tag is better to have an onclick event rather than an href. And when you have a lot of areas (for instance a map), is better to call the action by Class rather than by Id. Also it show me the following event that will trigger the action and also wll show the hover effect:

```
    onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('nameofclasshere')[0].click();"
```

This worked perfectly for me... credits to Sergio Morales for this answer :)